Character Typing through this website
As of now, I have been typing the pinyin for characters I want to use from Google Translate, then copying and pasting them to this site. Is there a way that I can type characters on this website rather than having to go on Google translate and go through that whole process? If not, maybe there can be a tool where you can orally say the words and they show up or just a plain Chinese character keyboard.

I am afraid Chinese character keyboard doesn't really exist, since Chinese keyboard layouts no much differences from the US keyboard. Certainly that there are some Chinese IME that you can choose from. Both google and Microsoft has Pinyin IME software to download, and, yeah, wubi(五笔) is another IME that decomposes chinese characters into components. Chrome also has a web-based IME plugin from the webstore, which is called "google input tools". I Hope it will help you.

I think at least it would be nice if there was mark up to convert pinyin tone numbers to tone marks. E.g. wrapping ma2 with performatted text  --> má. Typing tone-marked pinyin is not that straight-forward in every IME. 

This is quite a good idea.

@Ringil Do you have any idea how to propose this and who would be responsible for the implementation?

It seem there was something done before.. based on the Japanese Stack Exchange thing. I don't know what happened to it: http://meta.chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/315/should-we-add-the-enhancement-from-japanese-se-for-furigana-ruby-text-here-for-a
